# how to get html web page?

Tags: c#, html

I have to extract some information from html web page which contains the following table :

```
//Http://www.example.com/12.html
//<html ... >
<table>
<tr>
<td>HIIIIIIIIIII</td> // this is what I need from this page
</tr>
<tr><td>bla bla bla</td></tr>
</table>
```

any Ideas ?
 Thank u

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex), which provides good ways of parsing/reading HTML (even badly formed)

On this [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630527/c-using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-data-from-html-table), you can find a sample of how to extract table data.
And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack) contains sample of usage with LINQ.